# jQuery - how to get the final link after redirects to load() the content from URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery's `load()` function to load content from an element on another page getting link from the current page. This is currently my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $target = $('#post').find('h2 a').attr('href');
    $(".content").load($target + ".breadcrumb");
});
```

But this doesn't load content from the linked page, because the link isn't direct. There is a link that redirects to the final page. So jQuery loads a redirect from that link and takes me to the final page, instead of loading it on the current one.

How can I take the final URL and then assign it to the variable, then load the content from the final link without redirect?

E.g attr of a href is `"example.com/reports/29025/?action=find"`.

When you click on this link you are redirected to e.g: `"example.com/foundurl"`.

jQuery loads only `{"redirect":"example.com/reports/29025/?action=find","message":""}` from `"example.com/reports/29025/?action=find"` then redirects whole page to final instead of load

Comment: Nothing here? https://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+load+follow+redirect

Comment: This is not very clear at all. Are you asking how to get a url from next page and use that to `load()`? If so we have no idea what source of link is in next page

Comment: e.g attr of a href is
 "example.com/reports/29025/?action=find",
 when you click on this link you are redirected to e.g:
 "example.com/foundurl". 
jQuery loads only
 "{"redirect":"example.com/reports/29025/?action=find","message":""} "
 from "example.com/reports/29025/?action=find"
 then redirects whole page to final instead of load